# Android : Error E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! when try to View video

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, rtsp

i faced some problems when try to view video using VideoView. i always got message `Can't play this video` after that appears `failed to connect`

This is my url
`rtsp://136.243.10.198:1935/xxx_vod/xx_1455171793.mp4?key=b1fbf3e6e6edcc2bb6c75f879edf8bf0`

i got error on Log :

`E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri=rtsp://136.243.10.198:1935/xxx_vod/xx_1455171793.mp4?key=b1fbf3e6e6edcc2bb6c75f879edf8bf0`

and

`E/MediaPlayer: error (262, -1010)`

My Code :

```
path = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
videoView.setVideoPath(path);
videoView.requestFocus();

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: manually play the url in vlc

Comment: @Madhur : could you more detail how should i do?